# Why do I need to type c-u 0 first when I call byte-recompile-directory function in emacs?

Tags: emacs, compilation, org-mode

I was installing org-mode to my emacs. And a tutorial somewhere online tells me that I should do these steps: `c-u 0 m-x byte-recompile-directory<RET>`. And I know what I am doing of latter step (`m-x byte-recompile-directory<RET>`), but what's the meaning here of `"c-u 0"`?  Thanks!

Comment: The function is written to act differently with that argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `byte-recompile-directory` documentation:

> If the '.elc' file does not exist, normally this function **does not**
>   compile the corresponding '.el' file.  However, if the prefix argument
>   *ARG* is 0, that means do compile all those files.  A nonzero
>   *ARG* means ask the user, for each such '.el' file, whether to
>   compile it.  A nonzero *ARG* also means ask about each subdirectory
>   before scanning it.

<kbd>C-u</kbd> is the usual way to provide a numeric argument to interactive functions.  Unless you provide a zero arg with <kbd>C-u 0</kbd>, files that don't already have an `.elc` file won't be recompiled.